# Does Swype have custom auto replace?

Tags: swype

I love how Swype works but there are a few rather long phrases that I need to enter quite often, and wish I could enter faster, such as my email. I know the user dictionary will let me add custom entries, but that still requires me to Swype out all the characters.

I'm looking for a way to have a user defined phrase pop up as a suggestion when another, shorter, user defined phrase is entered. For example, I could then Swype E to M, and have my  email as a suggestion I can tap.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tap for those words, Swype's autocompletion will use your personal dictionary to finish the rest.

Comment: Useful trick, thank you. however for my email it needs half the letters tapped out for the entirety to pop up.

Comment: @Ampersand: I don't know if Swype's autocomplete would, like some other keyboards, "learn" your frequency of word usage and over time rank your email address higher. If it doesn't then it's definitely something Swype should add IMO.

Comment: I think more a matter of my email not being obscure enough, with too many possible words on the way to it. it would be a good feature to add though.